# Odoo employee image is not been showed on website template

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I'm trying to show the employee's picture (fields: hr_employee.image) on a website template. But the template just show the default picture for employees instead of the loaded image.

I tried this:

```
<span t-field="employee.image" t-options="{'widget': 'image', 'style': 'height:200px;width:200px;'}"/>
```

And also, tried this:

```
<div t-field="employee.image" t-options="{'widget': 'image', 'style': 'height:200px;width:200px;'}"/>
```

And this:

```
<img t-field="employee.image" t-options="{'widget': 'image', 'style': 'height:200px;width:200px;'}"/>
```

Template just show this:

[image: Template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid accessing images isn't as simple as that since you need sudo access to get them. If you're accessing the built-in employee module then the base model already provides this sudo access for you. Instead use the following:

```xml
<img t-att-src="image_data_uri(employee.image_1920)" style="max-height:85pt;max-width:90%"/>
```

The **1920** refers to the image's size. You can also use `employee.image_1024`, `employee.image_512`, `employee.image_256` or `employee.image_128`

If you're trying to access images from your own custom module then you'll need to update the .py file to access the image and provide its public url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `website.image_url` to define the image `src` attribute.

```
<img t-att-src="website.image_url(employee, 'image_medium')" class="img shadow rounded" alt="Employee"/>
```

The above code is taken from [website_hr](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/website_hr/views/website_hr_templates.xml#L30)
module (`aboutus` template)